# minecraft cannot find symbol

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

```
package net.minecraft.modproj;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class ItemPadding extends Item {
    public ItemPadding() {
        this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.MISC);
        this.setHasSubtypes(true);
    }

}
```

whenever i run the MCP931 recompiler on it, it tells me

```
src/minecraft/net/minecraft/item/ItemPadding.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class ItemPadding extends item {
                                 ^
```

The error did have the last word "item" in lowercase, but in the code wasn't in lowercase. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: are you think of net.minecraft.src.Item - http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2110/2014fa/L04-Hierarchy_static/mcp_doc/net/minecraft/src/Item.html

Comment: I think you're looking at a different class.

Comment: @shmosel what class am i looking at?

Comment: The class you posted is in `net.minecraft.modproj`, but your error is pointing to `net.minecraft.item`.